# Disable multi select dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to remove the default multi select enabled in dc.js charts.
Using renderlet:

```
past_linechart
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .width(1000).height(300)
  .dimension(dayDim)
  .group(day_count)
  .filter(weekday[current_time.getDay()])                    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]))
  .y(d3.scale.linear())
  .xAxisLabel("Date")
  .yAxisLabel("People in campus on average")
  .transitionDuration(500)
  .centerBar(true)    
  .gap(65)
  .elasticY(true)
  .elasticX(true)
  .xAxisPadding(10)
   .renderlet(function(chart) {
               chart.selectAll('rect.bar').on("click", function (d) {
                   chart.filter(null);
                   chart.filter(d.key);
         })
      })
  .xAxis().tickFormat();`
```

Gives me isfiltered on undefined error.
And also worked with event listener:
`on("filtered",function(chart,filter){
            dc.events.trigger(function(){
              chart.filterAll();
              chart.filter(filter);
            });`
Error

Comment: This has been done here: https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/bar-single-select.html